# How to split dataframe based on a range of values in a column and store them in separate files?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe created in spark after reading a table from postgres as below.

```
val url    = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
connectionProperties.setProperty("Username", "testDB")
connectionProperties.setProperty("Password", "123456")
val query  = "select * from testdb.datatable"
val dataDF = spark.read.jdbc(url, query1, connectionProperties)
```

I can see the count of data from the dataframe:

```
scala> dataDF.count
count: 3907891
```

sample output:

```
    scala> dataDF.take(5)
------------|----|--------|
|source_name|id  |location|
|-----------|----|--------|
|   DB2     | 10 |Hive    |
|   SAP     | 20 |Hive    |
| SQL Server| 17 |Hive    |
|   Oracle  | 21 |Hive    |
|   DB2     | 33 |Hive    |
|-----------|----|--------|
```

The dataframe contains a column "ID" of type "Integer" which contains data in a range of 10 to 50
Is there anyway I can split the dataframe into 4 different partitions and write each partition as a files based on the column ID of which each file contains data of ID in `file1: 10-20, file2: 21-30, file3: 31-40, file4: 41-50`

Comment: could you please add dataframe sample output.

Comment: Added it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the ids range, I would go with something simple.

```
val data = Seq(
      ("db2", 10, "Hive"),
      ("sap", 20, "Hive"),
      ("sql", 17, "Hive"),
      ("oracle", 21, "Hive"),
      ("server", 33, "Hive"),
      ("risk", 43, "Hive"),
    ).toDF("source_name", "id", "location")

val bucketed = data.withColumn("bucket",
         when($"id".between(0, 10), "1-10")
         .when($"id".between(11, 20), "11-20")
         .when($"id".between(21, 30), "21-30")
         .when($"id".between(31, 40), "31-40")
         .when($"id".between(41, 50), "41-50")
         .otherwise("50+"))

bucketed.write.option("header", true)
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .partitionBy("bucket")
      .csv("bucketing")
```

Comment: I see 4 buckets partitioned by ids. `bucket=1-10` has `1` file with ids 1 to 10, `bucket=11-20` has `1` file with ids 11 to 20. I am a bit confused.

Comment: My bad, I missed some data in the 'when' case. But this is great & working for me.